# Question regarding possibilities for Jordan normal form

Tags: jordan-normal-form

In this problem I am given a matrix $$B = \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
Also, I am supposing I have a matrix $A$ that is a complex $4 \times 4$ matrix with $AB = 0$
Now, I need to describe the possibilities
for the Jordan normal form of A.

EDIT: I should mention, all I tried was, considering an arbitrary complex matrix $A$ then we know that the fact that $AB = 0$ tells us that matrix $A$ has values only in the first and fourth row, so it has rank 2. Thus, I know $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & a & b & 0 \\
   0 & e & f & 0 \\
    0 & i & j & 0 \\
   0 & m & n & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$. Thus, from here I was trying to pplay around with the characteristic polynomioal of A but didn't get anwhere helpful.

I have no idea how I to continue, can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you at least figure out what $A$ might look like? Each column of $AB$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$. What constraints do you have on these columns?

Comment: You cannot say much. Only that the JF of $A$ has at least two Jordan blocks (which might be 1x1) corresponding to the zero eigenvalue.

Comment: @amd I added a few things I tried with A, I hope it helps but I didn't give me much information.

Comment: @amd I know that. That's why there are at least two Jordan blocks.

Comment: !You are right @amd! I made a silly error when computing this, sorry!

Comment: @amd "That’s a misstatement." No, it's correct. The zero matrix, e.g., has two Jordan blocks of size 1x1 each.